# Objective c converter app

Tags: ios, iphone, converters

I am working on a small converter app for my school project, an app that won't be published in App Store, just for school grade. I am wondering if anyone knows how did this developer in [this app](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/ad-free-unit-converter/id379646417?mt=8)

made connections for converting values? The simplest way i can imagine is with switch cases but that would make too much unnecessary code:

```
if (first column is distance) then if(second column is metres) 
case0:third column is yards -> do something
case1:third column is kilometers ->do something
case2:third column is metros ->do nothing
```

etc....

Thanks for answering.

EDIT:

Thanks for fast answer, this is what i made so far, iOS simulator is displaying correctly three column picker in which second two are displayed depending on the row of the first one. Can u tell me is this any good? Maybe some things are uneccesary complicated?

```
#import "konverterViewController.h"

@interface konverterViewController  ()

@end

@implementation konverterViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.fizVelicine  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"distance",@"mass" , nil];
    self.udaljenostJedinice  = [[NSArray alloc]         initWithObjects:@"meter", @"kilometer", @"yard", @"inch",  nil];
    self.masaJedinice  = [[NSArray alloc]         initWithObjects:@"kilogram",@"dekagram",@"gram",@"tone" , nil];
   }

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *retval = (id)view;
    if (!retval) {
        retval = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f,
                                                           [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].width,
                                                           [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].height)];

    }
    retval.opaque = NO;
    retval.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    retval.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    retval.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    if (component == 0) {
        retval.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        retval.text = [self.fizVelicine objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else if ([self.odabir isEqualToString:@"distance"]){
            retval.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            retval.text = [self.udaljenostJedinice objectAtIndex:row];
            }
    else  {
            retval.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            retval.text = [self.masaJedinice objectAtIndex:row];
             }

    return retval;
}

// returns the number of 'columns' to display.
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 3;


}

// returns the # of rows in each component..
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent: (NSInteger)component
{
    if(component== 0)
    {
        return [self.fizVelicine count];
    }
    else
    {
        if([self.odabir isEqualToString:@"distance"]){  return [self.udaljenostJedinice count];}
        else {return [self.masaJedinice count];}
    }


}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row   forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(component == 0)
    {
        return [self.fizVelicine objectAtIndex:row];
    }

    else {
        if([self.odabir isEqualToString:@"distance]){

            return [self.udaljenostJedinice objectAtIndex:row];}
        else {
            return [self.masaJedinice objectAtIndex:row];
        }
    }


}


- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row   inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (component == 0) {
        self.odabir=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@" , [self.fizVelicine objectAtIndex:row]];


        [pickerView reloadAllComponents];}


}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: That will work, but as you realized initially, the multi-branch if-else-if is a little clumsy, especially as the first segment gets more numerous.

Comment: Thanks, but my main issue is how will i know what formula to use to calculate data for conversion result. Somehow i need to know which row is in 1. 2. and 3. column so i can choose right formula for calculation. Do you maybe have idea how to do that? For example if 1. row is distance, 2. km and 3. metros, i need to multiply first value with 1000 to get correct result. I am wondering what is the easiest way to determine which operation to use.

Comment: sure.  I amended my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're puzzling over how to initialize the picker sections at the top.  I think you'll need a data structure that is an array of arrays:

```
@[@"distance", @[@"meters", @"inches", @"cubits", @"whatevers"],
  @"weight",   @[@"grams", // etc
```

Tell the picker that you have three segments.  The first segment can be manufactured (and cached, if you want) as the first elements of each sub-array.  The second two segments get their values from the data structure, indexed by the value of the first section.

EDIT; You'll probably want a data structure that helps you compute the conversion.  For each kind of measure, imagine an NxN table, where N is the number of units on the wheels.  A row let's you look up the left wheel setting and the column lets you look up the right wheel.  The table should contain what you need to do the calculation.  If all of the measures linearly related, like inches-meters, the table can simply contain floats (wrapped as NSNumber) conversion factors.

```
// conversion factors for distance, units as the first value, conversion factors in a subarray
// meters = 1*meters, 39.37*inches, 2.19*cubits, etc
NSArray *conversions = 
    @[@"meters", @[@1.0, @39.37, @2.19, //etc
      @"inches", // etc. conversions to meters inches cubits etc.
```

You might notice that this array contains some waste. Only half the table is needed, since inches->meters is just the reciprocal of meters->inches) but I think the space small enough to not worry about this.  You might also notice that the table is good only for simple linear relationships between units.  Centigrade to Fahrenheit will require a different treatment. The most general treatment for arbitrary conversions might be an array of blocks that carry out the computation.  But I suggest starting more simply.

EDIT AGAIN:

Now, to get a conversion formula, get the current picker selections and look up a conversion factor:

```
NSInteger fromUnitsIndex = [self.picker selectedRowInComponent:1];
NSArray *fromArray = self.conversions[fromUnitsIndex];

// the second member of this array is an array of conversion factors
NSArray *conversionNumbers = fromArray[1];

NSInteger toUnitsIndex = [self.picker selectedRowInComponent:2];
NSNumber *conversionNumber = conversionNumbers[toUnitsIndex];
```

It sounds like a fun project.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, I will start from this. Also you probably in my mess of an explanation didn't understand main question which is how can I know which operation to use based on values in 2. and 3. column. It is hard for me to explain because english isn't my best language. But probably somewhere there must be some IF loops where i test what is currenty selected in 2. and 3. column, should my display write meters or kilometers or yards or whatever.

Comment: Sure.  I edited again to illustrate (1) how to know the position of the picker wheels, and (2) how to use those to lookup into the two-dimensional array.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try and do something like this. Even tho i am unclear how to read current value selected row in 2. and 3. column in picker. Because that data is chaining based on values in first column.

Comment: Can u please look at this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173193/showing-data-in-picker

Comment: yes, thanks in any case. I just accepted your answer, didn't know that you can do that until 2 minutes ago.

Comment: Hi again :D Could you please look at this if you got 2 minutes spare? Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21340646/ios-conveter-app-connections-between-measures/21340779?noredirect=1#21340779

Comment: Sure.  Same thing I'm saying here above.  I was much more explicit in the other answer.  Paste that into a new class and try it.  (I know it's for school, so please before you understand it before turning it in).