# Showing data in picker

Tags: ios, plist, uipickerview

Can someone please explain to me why my picker is not showing any data when i load from plist

This is plist:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>England</key>
    <array>
        <string>Chelsea</string>
        <string>Arsenal</string>
    </array>
    <key>Spain</key>
    <array>
        <string>Barca</string>
        <string>Real</string>
    </array>
 </dict>
</plist>`
```

This is part of viewController.m

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSURL *plistFile = [bundle URLForResource:@"myPListFile" withExtension:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:plistFile];
    self.countryClubs = dictionary;

    NSString *selectedCountry = [self.countries objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *array = [countryClubs objectForKey:selectedCountry];
    self.clubs = array;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (component == 0)
        return [self.countries count];
    return [self.clubs count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
        forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (component == 0)
        return [self.countries objectAtIndex:row];
    return [self.clubs objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
       inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
       if (component == 0) {
         NSString *selectedCountry = [self.countries objectAtIndex:row];
         NSArray *array = [countryClubs objectForKey:selectedCountry];
         self.clubs = array;
         [picker selectRow:0 inComponent:1 animated:YES];
         [picker reloadComponent:1];
    }
}
```

in viewController.h i got

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong)NSDictionary *countryClubs;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSArray *countries;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSArray *clubs;
```

and in viewController.m i got:

```
@synthesize countryClubs=_countryClubs;
@synthesize countries=_countries;
@synthesize clubs=_clubs;
```

If anyone could explain why is picker blank i would appreciate it really much, it seems to that plist is not loaded because if i write :

```
self.clubs  = [[NSArray alloc]      initWithObjects:@"milimetar",@"centimetar",@"metar",@"kilometar",@"inc",@"stopa",@"jard",@"milja", nil];
```

picker is showing data.

Comment: Where do set `self.countries`? Is your file really named *exactly* `myPListFile.plist`? Note the uppercase `L` after the `P`.

Comment: Have you verified that the picker's `delegate` and `dataSource` are actually set?

Comment: yes it is named myPListFile.plist and it is in Supporting Files directory.

Comment: yes, i got in viewController.h @interface konverterViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>

Comment: I don't know what that means. It's impossible to set the picker's `delegate` and `dataSource` in a header file. It can be done either in code or in interface builder.

Comment: I am new at objective c you please excuse me for not knowing some basics. But the thing is if don't load data from plist and just write in my code self.clubs  = [[NSArray alloc]      initWithObjects:@"milimetar",@"centimetar",@"metar",@"kilometar",@"inc",@"stopa",@"jard",@"milja", nil];  then picker is working normal and he is showing his columns and rows with data in it

Comment: @rmaddy I have found out that plist is loading correctly, problem is that self.countries and self.clubs is empty when app starts so picker is empty, do you have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: As I said, where do you set `self.countries`? Hint: you don't. And you are basing `self.clubs` on the uninitialized (and pointless) ivar `countryClubs`.

Comment: @rmaddy THanks, can u maybe help me with that? I am stuck on this for hours already :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `viewDidLoad` should be:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSURL *plistFile = [bundle URLForResource:@"myPListFile" withExtension:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:plistFile];

    self.countryClubs = dictionary;
    self.countries = [dictionary allKeys];

    NSString *selectedCountry = self.countries[0];
    NSArray *array = self.countryClubs[selectedCountry];
    self.clubs = array;
}
```

In your `didSelectRow:` method, change:

```
NSArray *array = [countryClubs objectForKey:selectedCountry];
```

to:

```
NSArray *array = self.countryClubs[selectedCountry];
```

Also get rid of all of your `@synthesize` lines. If you are using any tutorial that talks about using `@synthesize` then it is out of date. Also get rid of any ivars you may have explicitly declared for your properties.

Comment: can i ask you one more question? How can i display on a label what i currently selected in second column?

Comment: Add the code in your `didSelectRow:` method. Just check for changes to the other component. Update the label with the value.